# How to parse text file and save lines to dict as key and list of values

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse many ".txt" files and store some rows as key and some others as values in a dict. 
Method should be as abstract as it can be, because the overall file structure is the same across files, **BUT** some records can have less or more fields than others, and the same field can have less or more lines in different records.

Text files come formatted like this one but often with more or less properties:

```
Autore principale:
     Christie, Agatha
Titolo:
     La mia vita / Agatha Christie ; traduzione di Maria Giulia Castagnone
Pubblicazione:
     Milano : Oscar Mondadori, 1995
Descrizione fisica:
     636 p. ; 20 cm.
Collezione:
    Oscar narrativa ; 1563
        Oscar scrittori moderni
Titolo uniforme:
    An autobiography | Christie, Agatha
Numeri:
    [ISBN]  978-88-04-52225-6 9. rist. 2013
Nomi:
     Christie, Agatha
        [Traduttore]  Castagnone, Mariagiulia
Soggetti:
    Christie, Agatha
Classificazione Dewey:
    823.912 (19.) NARRATIVA INGLESE. 1900-1945
Lingua di pubblicazione:
    ita
Paese di pubblicazione:
    IT
Codice identificativo:
    IT\ICCU\LIA\0962595
```

Eeach line ending with a **':'** should be a key and the following one (or *the following ones* sometimes, as you can see) a list of values for that key.

Expected output:

```
{'Autore principale:': ['Christie, Agatha'],
 'Titolo:': ['\x88La \x89mia vita / Agatha Christie ; traduzione di Maria Giulia Castagnone'],
 'Pubblicazione:': ['Milano : Oscar Mondadori, 1995'],
 'Descrizione fisica:': ['636 p. ; 20 cm.'],
 'Collezione:': ['Oscar narrativa ; 1563', 'Oscar scrittori moderni'],
 'Titolo uniforme:': ['\x88An \x89autobiography | Christie, Agatha'],
 'Numeri:': ['[ISBN]  978-88-04-52225-6 9. rist. 2013'],
 'Nomi:': ['Christie, Agatha'],
...
...}
```

so far i've come to this python code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    record_keys = [elem for elem in lines if elem.endswith(':')]

    # here comes the loop:
    length = len(lines) 
    i = 0
    values = []
    while i < length:
        if lines[i] in record_keys:
            current_key = record_keys.index(lines[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            if lines[i] == lines[-1]:
                val = [i for i in lines[lines.index(lines[i]):]]
                values.append(val)
                i+=1
            else:
                if len(values) > 0 and lines[i] in values[-1]:
                    print({f'string {lines[i]}} already in [values], skipping')
                    i+=1
                else:
                    next_key = record_keys[current_key+1]
                    val = [i for i in lines[lines.index(lines[i]):lines.index(next_key)]]
                    values.append(val)
                    i+=1

    # dict from zip object
    isbn_dict = dict(zip(record_keys, values))
```

i got this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

resulting dict:

```
{'Autore principale:': ['Christie, Agatha'],
 'Titolo:': ['\x88La \x89mia vita / Agatha Christie ; traduzione di Maria Giulia Castagnone'],
 'Pubblicazione:': ['Milano : Oscar Mondadori, 1995'],
 'Descrizione fisica:': ['636 p. ; 20 cm.'],
 'Collezione:': ['Oscar narrativa ; 1563', 'Oscar scrittori moderni'],
 'Titolo uniforme:': ['\x88An \x89autobiography | Christie, Agatha'],
 'Numeri:': ['[ISBN]  978-88-04-52225-6 9. rist. 2013'],
 'Nomi:': ['Christie, Agatha',
  'Titolo:',
  '\x88La \x89mia vita / Agatha Christie ; traduzione di Maria Giulia Castagnone',
  'Pubblicazione:',
  'Milano : Oscar Mondadori, 1995',
  'Descrizione fisica:',
  '636 p. ; 20 cm.',
  'Collezione:',
  'Oscar narrativa ; 1563',
  'Oscar scrittori moderni',
  'Titolo uniforme:',
  '\x88An \x89autobiography | Christie, Agatha',
  'Numeri:',
  '[ISBN]  978-88-04-52225-6 9. rist. 2013',
  'Nomi:',
  'Christie, Agatha',
  '[Traduttore]  Castagnone, Mariagiulia'],
 'Soggetti:': ['823.912 (19.) NARRATIVA INGLESE. 1900-1945'],
 'Classificazione Dewey:': ['ita'],
 'Lingua di pubblicazione:': ['IT'],
 'Paese di pubblicazione:': ['IT\\ICCU\\LIA\\0962595']}
```

result is a mess, caused probably by something in the block:

```
else:
    if len(values) > 0 and lines[i] in values[-1]:
        print({f'string {lines[i]}} already in [values], skipping')
        i+=1
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that should solve :

```
with open('t6.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    d = {}
    keys = []
    vals = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.endswith(':'):
            keys.append(line)
        else:
            vals.append(line)
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        d[k] = lines[lines.index(k)+1:lines.index(keys[keys.index(k)+1])]
    print(d)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
{'Autore principale:': ['Christie, Agatha'], 
'Titolo:': ['La mia vita / Agatha Christie ; traduzione di Maria Giulia Castagnone'], 
'Pubblicazione:': ['Milano : Oscar Mondadori, 1995'], 
'Descrizione fisica:': ['636 p. ; 20 cm.'], 
'Collezione:': ['Oscar narrativa ; 1563', 'Oscar scrittori moderni'], 
'Titolo uniforme:': ['An autobiography | Christie, Agatha'], 
'Numeri:': ['[ISBN]  978-88-04-52225-6 9. rist. 2013'], 
'Nomi:': ['Christie, Agatha', '[Traduttore]  Castagnone, Mariagiulia'], 
'Soggetti:': ['Christie, Agatha'], 
'Classificazione Dewey:': ['823.912 (19.) NARRATIVA INGLESE. 1900-1945'], 
'Lingua di pubblicazione:': ['ita'], 
'Paese di pubblicazione:': ['IT']}
```

Comment: i noticed that your code has a minor issue: 

'Milano : Oscar Mondadori, 1995':

is not a key but a value.

Workaround should be to not use:

if ':' in line:
            keys.append(line)

but

if line.endswith(':'):
    keys.append(line)

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you should avoid looping on "indexes" and instead using dict comprehension and for-each loops:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    record_keys = { elem for elem in lines if elem.endswith(':') } # a set
    isbn_dict = { elem : set() for elem in record_keys }   # a dict of sets

    current_key = None
    for line in lines:
        if line in record_keys:
            current_key = line
        else:
            isbn_dict[current_key].add(line)
```